# Java - Using Scanner reading from Socket InputStream

Tags: java, outputstream

I am sorry because I can't think of any better title.
I has a server-client program written in java that server send a string that end with new line character `\n` the client read from `socket.getInputStream()` if input has next line by using Scanner

on server-side

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
PrintWrite send = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream);
send.print("Server has succeeded to proccess your request \n" + show(ID));
send.flush();
```

The show(ID) is a function that return a string which already contain next line character in it.
on client side

```
Socket socket = new Socket(HOST,PORT);
Scanner read = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream);
public Boolean ServerResponse(){
    System.out.println("please wait");
    Boolean result=false;
    while(true){
        if(read.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.println("has next");
            String msg = read.nextLine();
            System.out.println(msg);
            if(msg.contains("succeeded")){
                result = true;
            }

        }else{
            System.out.println("finished reading server respone");
            return result;
        }

    }
}
```

when I tried to run this. `"finished reading server respone"` is never printed and there is no `has next` after the last line send by `Server` is printed which assume that there is no next line character. However the `else` block is never executed. Strangely when I terminate the `Server`, it is printed. Can anyone please explain this to me and what I must do that I don't need to terminate the server for that line to be printed?

Answer (score 2):

From [Scanner#hasNextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine%28%29) documentation:

> Returns true if there is another line in the input of this scanner.
>   This method may block while waiting for input. The scanner does not
>   advance past any input.

Meaning that it will return `true` if next line is available, **not** that it will return `false` when no next line is available for processing. It might be waiting for another line to show up, though.

Comment: So that mean it only return false if there is input but without next line. For no input it will block? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not closing the PrintWriter in the server side.

As `Socket` and `PrintWriter` implements autoclosable interface, you can use a try with resources block to close the resources when the server has finished with them.

```
try (Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
     PrintWriter send = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream);) {
    send.print("Server has succeeded to proccess your request \n" + show(ID));
}
```

When you call the method `hasNextLine` in your scanner in the client side, it blocks waiting for input.

If you shutdown your server, the stream is closed and the method `hasNextLine` return false and the  `finished reading server response` is displayed in the client.

Comment: So that mean after each time Server sending something, it must close the PrintWriter and the next time it must create new PrintWriter. Is closing PrintWriter close the OuputStream as well?

Comment: Your client is being blocked in the `hasNextLine` method waiting for input from the server. If the server is not going to send anything more and close the stream, the client will print `finished reading server respone`. If your server is going to send more data, you shouldn't close the stream and I guess your client is OK waiting for more input.